# Django allauth linking multiple accounts from mobile app

Tags: android, django, authentication, django-allauth

I have managed to get an independent FB & twitter login.
User Logs in on phone -> passes access token to server -> use AllAuth to Login

My problem now is, if user selects "connect with google" after logging in using FB. How do I associate the Fb login to Google login?

The allAuth site says it enables this, but the documentation/examples are dismal.